# Any netty 4 documentation available?

Tags: documentation, netty

I know Norman is working on the Netty 4 book as I've been following the tweets, but was wondering if there are any pieces available to help someone who hasn't worked with Netty 3.  I have looked a little at the existing 3.x articles, but I think it would be easier to understand the primary components without having to learn 3.x and then mentally apply the New and Noteworthy section to bridge the gap.

For now, I'm just trying to go through the example/test code to see how it's used, but any overview/fundemental documentation would be great.  If not, that's ok - just thought I'd check.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nothing out there at the moment except what you find on the Blog and the javadocs. I'm currently working hard on getting the javadocs up-to-date before our next release, so you may find all you need in there. An other source of informations is like you said the example module which contains a lot examples for all kind of use-cases.

Hopefully the MEAP of the Netty book will start in not so far future. But we will see..